# Прижать элементы к краям вертикально

Tags: css

У меня есть колонка, с заголовком и карточками в ней. Мне необходимо сделать еще один блок внутри, который прижимался бы к нижнему краю. Я использую библиотеку `styled-components`.

css для колонки

```
export const StyledColumn = styled.div`
  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ebecf0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
`
```

css для черного блока

```
export const AddCard = styled.div`
  //position: relative;
  //top: 70%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
`
```

То что закомментировано - попытки сделать это. Подскажите как это грамотно сделать?

[image]

Comment: Про использованную вами библиотеку ничего не знаю. Но если предположить, что в природе не существует flex, то я бы прописал родительскому блоку `position: relative;`, чёрному блоку - `position: absolute;` и `bottom: 5px;` ну или сколько там у вас в макете. Само собой, ширину чёрному блоку тоже следовало бы задать.

Answer (score 0):

Про библиотеку тоже не знаю, но, если просто, то объедините белые карточки в один контейнер, а черный блок в другой, и раздвиньте флексом.

Вот так, например:

```css
.column {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ebecf0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
 
 .card {
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
  
  
.black-block {
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
 }
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="black-block"></div>
</div>
```